# Почему после отправки через ajax не видит POST?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Подскажите 
Есть форма

```
<form class="sms-form" >
<input type="hidden" name="ttns" value="<?php echo $page->crm_ttn?>">
<input type="hidden" name="phone" value="<?php echo $page->crm_phone?>">
<button class="sms" type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

Я обрабатываю через ajax

```
function smsSend() {
  var msge  = jQuery('.sms-form').serialize();
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/some.php',
    data: msge,
    success: function(data) {
      alert('Отправлено' + data);
    },
    error:  function(xhr, str){
      alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

и когда проверяю в файле . some.php "echo $_POST['ttns']";
ничего не выводит . Что я делаю не так?

---

перебираю нажатие кнопок так

```
var formSubmi = document.querySelectorAll('.sms');
  for (i = 0; i < formSubmi.length; i++){
  formSubmi[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    smsSend()
  });
  }
```

Comment: `console.log(msge);` - ??

Comment: console log выдает ttns=&phone=0501917617&ttns=20450088566939&phone=5

Comment: Значит у вас несколько форм с классом `sms-form`, jQUery их все и сериализует. Зачем вы вообще перебираете все кнопки и отдельно вешаете хендлер на каждую?

Comment: А как мне по другому задать сабмиту preventDefault для того чтоб не перегружало страницу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо всех странных кодов которые вешают отдельный обработчик на каждую кнопку и функций, надо сделать вот что:

```
jQuery('.sms-form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // `jQuery(this)` это форма которая сабмитится в данный момент
  var msge  = jQuery(this).serialize(); 
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/some.php',
    data: msge,
    success: function(data) {
      alert('Отправлено' + data);
    },
    error:  function(xhr, str){
      alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо . Заранее извиняюсь - в js новичок . Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Все мы когда-то и в чем-то новички)

Answer (score 0):

```
var formSubmi = document.querySelectorAll('.sms');
  for (i = 0; i < formSubmi.length; i++){
  formSubmi[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    smsSend($(this).closest("form"));
  });
}

function smsSend($form) {
  var msge  = $form.serialize();
  jQuery.ajax({
  ...
```